# Onchange function for district in odoov10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, onchange, odoo-10

I have to two many2one type field. In field local region "Hong kong", "Kawloon" and "New Terriotories". And in another many2one fields district related to these regions. And i want that when i select a 'local region' then district avail only related to that region.

My code is here:

**Python Code:**

```
class district_code_form(models.Model):

    _name = 'district.districe.code'

    _rec_name = 'district_mainn'



    district_mainn = fields.Char('District Value')

    district_ss = fields.One2many('district.district', 'district_id', string="District Workflow")


class district_form(models.Model):

    _name = 'district.district'

    _rec_name = 'district'



    district_id = fields.Many2one('district.district.code', string='Districts Id', ondelete='cascade', index=True, copy=False)

    district = fields.Char("District")



class customer_information(models.Model):

    _inherit = "res.partner"




@api.onchange('district_table_case')

    def _onchange_district_table(self):

        if self.district_table_case:

            return {'domain': {'district_table': [('district_table_case', '=', self.district_table_case)]}}

        else:

            return {'domain': {'district_table': []}}



district_table_case = fields.Many2one('district.districe.code')

    district_table = fields.Many2one('district.district', change_default=True, default=_onchange_district_table)
```

**XML Code:**

```
 <field name="district_table_case"/>

 <field name="district_table"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code by

```
@api.onchange('district_table_case')

def _onchange_district_table(self):

    if self.district_table_case:

        return {'domain': {'district_table': [('district_table_case', '=', self.district_table_case.id)]}}

    else:

        return {'domain': {'district_table': []}}
```

And also there is no field named district_table_case in district.district model

Comment: It shows following Error:

ValueError: Invalid field u'district_table_case' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'district_table_case', u'=', 1) on district_district (ctx: )>"

Comment: yes see my answer, There is no field district_table_case in your model

Comment: This field in the inherited res.partner model. See, at the last of code.

Comment: you can only give domain for the available fields. Go to Odoo documentation and find the concepts